# How do i select an object from local json and pass it to the state?

Tags: reactjs, state, cart

I need to pass the object selected to the empty array in my state.
*cars[]: holds the entire JSON
*carsPurchase[]: is where I want to move the selected item

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cars: [],
    carsPurchase: [],
    total: 0,
    purchased: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ cars: cars });
  }

  addingCarHandler = id => {
    const oldCars = { ...this.state.cars };

    const oldPurchasedTotal = this.state.purchased;
    const updatedPurchasedTotal = oldPurchasedTotal + 1;

    const updatedPurchase = { ...this.state.carsPurchase };
    updatedPurchase[id] = oldCars;

    const priceAddition = CAR_PRICES[id];
    const oldTotal = this.state.total;
    const newPrice = oldTotal + priceAddition;

    this.setState({
      total: newPrice,
      carsPurchase: updatedPurchase,
      purchased: updatedPurchasedTotal
    });
  };
}
```

this is what im getting in console.log when im selecting a car(the whole json and not only selected item object):

````
0: {id: 0, name: "Ferrari", price: 1000000, description: "Very Fast!", img: "https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/73cf1698c3c11f3330d4e0…gtb-car-5a74a36316ab65.4869115715175934430929.png"}
1: {id: 1, name: "Porsche", price: 1200000, description: "Super Fast", img: "https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/013c38262b009a5b7776bc…lue-car-5a7496427e19c9.5257200415175900825165.png"}
2: {id: 2, name: "Bugatti", price: 3200000, description: "Extremely Fast", img: "https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/c018e60203b9880f52bb3d…wBvbz==/5a34cd74940df1.0678198215134099086064.png"}
3: {id: 3, name: "Maserati", price: 800000, description: "Kinda Fast", img: "https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/70d2499127f097ad5b4ae2…aserati-5ac3bb7b112244.0465438015227769550702.png"}
4: {id: 4, name: "BMW", price```
````

Comment: i tried using filter but its still doesnt work... now it only gives me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter` function:

```
const updatedPurchase = this.state.cars.filter( car => car.id == id )
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to use the filter  in your this situation by `const arryfoundThatAtchiveCondation=this.state.cars.filter(car_item=> car_item==id);`
or use some package helper  but I not sutable  rgnizr  it is simple to use the filter is lodash lok to this link [enter link description here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find)

Comment: i tried it and it also helped me figure out whats my problem... im "stuck" on the first index (car) unlike the car i click on... so its always comparing what ever i click to the first car and thats always the object i get: the first car.   any advice???

Comment: i suggest for you giving every car index or key and